# Rviz motion_planning Error: Failed to load library

Tags: ros, motion-planning, moveit-setup-assistant, moveit-tutorial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I am following through the Moveit! Industrial Robot Tutorial and got stuck.

when I add motion planning or any from the moveit_ros_visualization folder, it will show the same error:

> MotionPlanning
> The class required for this display, 'moveit_rviz_plugin/MotionPlanning', could not be loaded.

> Error:
> Failed to load library /opt/ros/hydro/lib/libmoveit_motion_planning_rviz_plugin.so. Make sure that you are calling the PLUGINLIB_EXPORT_CLASS macro in the library code, and that names are consistent between this macro and your XML. Error string: Could not load library (Poco exception = liborocos-kdl.so.1.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)

However, the libmoveit_motion_planning_rviz_plugin.so  is right in its place.

How can I solve this?

[image: This is the screenshot]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/194341/rviz-motion_planning-error:-failed-to-load-library/) by [sara](https://answers.ros.org/users/20392/sara/) on ROS Answers with karma: 35 on 2014-10-06

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like the MoveIt plugin for Rviz depends on a particular version of the Orocos KDL library that isn't present.

I would start by making sure that all of your packages are up to date:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-10-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2014-10-07**:
See also [moveit_ros/issues/482](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit_ros/issues/482).

**Comment by [anonymous28838](https://answers.ros.org/users/28838/anonymous28838/) on 2017-06-09**:
Do you have an alternate solution for this?
http://answers.ros.org/question/263585/rviz-motion-planning-error-failed-to-load-motion-planning-plugin-library/

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2017-06-09**:
Nope. It looks like the plugin is compiled against packages that use OpenCV 2.4, and can't be used with a different version.